# How to I stop my game object from moving on the y axis in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, rotation

I making a game in unity where the objective of the game is to move a cube along a platform by rotating in onto the next face in the direction that you want to move it towards.

in order to finish the game you have to move the cube along the faces from the starting platform (pink) to the end platform (green) -
[example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsYqC.png)

I have a check (using ray-cast) to see which platform the cube is sitting on to determine if the cube is on the end platform so that i can trigger the new level to be loaded into the game as well as play an end animation where the cube shrinks down into the end platform.

However the problem that i am having is that when ever the cube is rotated on to another adjacent platform the y value is changing even though the cube is still sitting at the correct height on the platforms. For example when starting the game the cube is at y = 0 when moving the cube it changes to something different every time sometimes its a positive number and sometimes its negative, but in order for the ray-cast to work it always needs to be at 0 as the ray-cast length is only 0.5 from the centrr of the cube out of each face.

If I play the game and pause and change the y position in the inspector back to 0 the ray-cast then works.

How do I prevent the cubes y position from changing without freezing it on the y axis as there is nor rigid body on the cube as it completely destroys the movement if i add one to it.

[this is an example of the game it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olwau.gif) - the movement of the game works but because the y position is changing on the cube the ray-casts are not reaching the platforms even thought the cube looks like its sitting on them.

[this is my code to roll the cube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GU6u.png)

Comment: Include your movement code

Comment: Can you also provide some footage (gif/video) of the issue?

Comment: you don't see anything happen while playing the game. but ill try

Comment: have you tried setting the transform y axis to 0 every frame ?

Answer (score 0):

For cases like this one I use a Rigidbody component and set the Freeze option, in biped Characters I use Freeze Rotation on X and Z axes.

I would use **Freeze Position on the Y axe** in your concrete case.

https://docs.unity.cn/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html

Comment: I Cant use a rigid body as said above as it changes the movement of the cube completely

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, but did you try to set the Rigidbody to Non-Kinematic to avoid changing the movement? As I only see the Ienumerator of your code, I do not know what is happening under the hod. Maybe think in another solution like adding a Agent component to the cube, make the surface navigation static, bake it, and let the navigation and Animator Blend Tree perform de animations according to the side of displacement of the agent

Comment: i tried that but originally it didn't work, i've just tried it again and it seems to be working now so thank you.

Comment: I am happy about my proposal helped you to make it works. You´re welcome